# Integrate ionic 5 with zoom

Tags: integration, ionic5

i m trying to integrate ionic 5 with zoom,
i m following this tutorial : https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/hybrid-frameworks/ionic/getting-started/install

1) i added the plugin using capacitor

2) did the set up in the ionic app

3) Project is building properly

but when i m trying to build it in android studio it gives

**ERROR: Failed to resolve: :mobilertc**

so i added the 2 libraries of zoom 
which are commonlib and mobilertc

[image: Added module]

then i went to dependancy and added the dependencies
[image: Dependacy]

But still i m getting the same error.

**ERROR: Failed to resolve: :mobilertc**

Plz help

Answer (score 1):

Please install these two plugins
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter

and make sure you have
compileSdkVersion: 29+
buildToolsVersion: 29+
minSdkVersion: 21
in build.gradle file